# Are diseases more common in certain regions?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I was playing my Abbasid Caliphate game recently and saw a smallpox outbreak pop up in the south.

Normally this wouldn't be noteworthy but I stopped and realized that I hadn't seen one in many hours. In my Ireland  game it seemed like I rarely went an hour without an outbreak, and in Norway one every two hours seemed normal even before I expanded beyond the borders of a single Kingdom. So that got me wondering, are disease outbreaks more common in some places than in others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what they've exposed in the text files, here's the information you can get about a disease:

```
tuberculosis = {
contagiousness = 0.2
outbreak_chance = 0.02
effect = {
    city_tax_modifier = -0.5
    supply_limit = -4
    max_attrition = 0.05
}
icon = 1
tooltip = TUBERCULOSIS_INFO
months = 24
trait = has_tuberculosis
always_get_message = no

timeperiod = {
    start_date = 769.1.1
    end_date = 1452.1.1     

    one_only = no
}
```

}

By what I can see here, it doesn't appear so. None of the diseases in the file have anything other than a flat "outbreak_chance" as far as that is concerned.

Comment: IIRC `contagiousness` iirc is the chance of spreading provinces. Not sure how that works exactly.

Comment: It's either that or the chance of your characters actually catching it when it appears in a province. Maybe both? Unfortunately the actual details of how the game uses these values isn't shown to us.